# Is it possible to put a probability space into the Hierarchy of mathematical spaces?

Tags: probability, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

This is the figure of Hierarchy of mathematical spaces in this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space).

a [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) is understood as a measurable function defined on a **probability space** whose outcomes are typically real numbers

so, is it possible to put a probability space into this Hierarchy of mathematical spaces?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Probability spaces are a special kind of measure spaces (just those with total measure 1). There's no intrinsic relation between measures and topologies, or between measures and metrics. You can put a measure (even a probability measure) on any set you want (Exception: you can't put a probability measure on the empty set).

Comment: It’s also worth noting that there are many different ways that a set can be turned into a measure space. There is a very particular way that you can turn a topological/metric space into a measure space such that the two agree nicely (with Borel measures), but frequently we are interested in other measures that have nothing to do with the underlying topology or existence of a metric. Likewise, I think any measurable space can be turned into a topological space by declaring that the measurable sets are open, but this is only one of the many ways a topology can be made and it is not that common.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn‘t fit into this total order: a probability space is simply a measure space such that the measure of the whole space is $1$. A measure can be put on any set and a priori it doesn‘t have any relation to topological spaces or metric spaces.